# rvm + passenger (stand alone) GemNotFound

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm, passenger

I am new to Rails and trying to deploy an application to a CentOS server.  I have chosen to use RVM as it seems to be highly recommended.  I am open to Nginx, Apache or Passenger Stand Alone -- whatever works and is easiest.

I have struggled with this install but think that I have successfully cleaned up after myself and have now followed the instructions for single user (non-sudo) rvm install (including ssh).

One thing I don't understand is how Passenger should be installed (given that RVM is being used)?:

```
gem install passenger
sudo gem install passenger
rvmsudo gem install passenger
```

I assume that however it is installed, it should be started in the same way.  I have tried each of these methods, but encounter problems in all cases.

When I started Passenger with sudo, I received:

> Could not find factory_girl-3.6.1 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)

I noticed that sometimes my ruby version would be 1.8.7 even if I set it to 1.9.3-p194 with RVM, so I uninstalled 1.8.7 (had been installed prior to RVM) and reinstalled 1.9.3-p194 (using RVM and specifying openssl again).  I reinstalled passenger

Now when I do "sudo passenger start", I just get a new prompt as though nothing happened.  Also if I do "sudo gem install passenger".

Finally, I notice that if I start passenger with rvmsudo that the webserver does start, however it gives an error to the console:

> /usr/bin/evn: ruby: Permission denied

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use `sudo`:

```
gem install passenger
passenger start
```

However if you used `sudo`/`rvmsudo` - you could change permissions of some of the directories, if any of them are reported as not accessible then use this commands to fix them:

```
chown -R $USER: {dir}
chmod -R u+rwX,g+rwX,o+rX,o-w {dir}
```